# How to fix the following warning: `WARN: The resource for '' is not found, drilling down to the details of this test won't be possible.`

Tags: python-3.x, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

My abridged `sonar-project.properties` files is as follows:

```
# Sources
sonar.sources=felix
sonar.sources.inclusions=**/**.py
sonar.exclusions=**/test_*.py,**/**.pyc,felix/utils/*,**/*.iml

# Linter
sonar.python.pylint=/usr/local/bin/pylint
sonar.python.pylint_config=.pylintrc
sonar.python.pylint.reportPath=pylint-report.txt

# Coverage / Unit Tests
sonar.tests=./tests
sonar.test.inclusions=**/test_**.py
sonar.python.xunit.skipDetails=false
#DEFAULT VALUES: sonar.python.xunit.reportPath=xunit-reports/xunit-result-*.xml
#DEFAULT VALUES: sonar.python.coverage.reportPath=coverage-reports/*coverage-*.xml
```

The abridged source code tree is like so:

```
├── felix
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── process.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   └── spark.cpython-35.pyc
│   ├── felix.iml
│   ├── process.py
│   ├── spark.py
│   └── utils
│       └── utils.py
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
├── sonar-project.properties
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   └── test_process.cpython-35-PYTEST.pyc
│   ├── cia-spark.iml
│   ├── data
│   └── test_process.py
└── tox.ini
```

I'm getting the following warning, though, when I run the `sonar-scanner`: `WARN: The resource for '' is not found, drilling down to the details of this test won't be possible`

Could someone, please, let me know why I'm getting this warning and how can I get rid of / fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Here is the line before the warning line:
`INFO: Processing report '/root/jenkins/workspace/CIA_Cloud_Insights_cia-spark_dev/xunit-reports/xunit-result-tests.xml'`
Could it be that it's stumbling over a newly created folder and I just need to exclude it, may be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be with the Pylint integrated into the Pytest call.
The parent Pytest call generated a unit testing report, which had empty classnames for additional "empty" tests that Pylint came up with.
SonarQube warned about those empty classnames.
I ended up removing Pylint Pytest integration and just running Pylint as a separate step from Pytest.

Answer (score 3):

I received this warning because I was excluding test files from analysis. I see than in your properties you are excluding your tests as well:

`sonar.exclusions=**/test_*.py,**/**.pyc,felix/utils/*,**/*.iml`

This will prevent sonar from calculating the number of tests and their pass/fail status as shown in the open source [here](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-python/blob/32ab65a8eae21842e6759051e9f154036fe56c70/sonar-python-plugin/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/python/xunit/PythonXUnitSensor.java#L169)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I will try removing tests from the exclusions of the main sonar sources spec and see how it behaves, then report back.

Comment: Well, removing the `**/test_*.py` part from `sonar.exclusions` did not help with eliminating that warning...
In fact, these tests are still listed as excluded, I think, because they are included in the coverage part...